# Computing conditional expectation of conditional expectation given the same variable

Tags: probability, expected-value

I've been working under the assumption that

$$
(1)\qquad \mathbf{E}[Y|X] = \mathbf{E}[\mathbf{E}(Y|X)|X]
$$

in order to be able to conclude that $ \mathbf{E}[Y|X] = \mathbf{E}[\mathbf{E}(Y|X,Z)|X] $

However, I want to know that what I am assuming (1) is actually correct, but I don't seem to come up with an idea to prove it besides just intuition. My thought process is: the expected value of the expectation of a variable (Y) given another (X), given the same variable (X) does not change the fact that the only given variable is X. Thanks in advance, I've been working on it for hours and I know there must be something obvious I'm missing, but I'm too frustrated to notice at this point.

Comment: What is your definition of $E(X|Y)$? If you know the general definition of conditional expectation given a sigma algebra then (1)  is immediate from the fact that $E(X|Y)$ is already measurable w.r.t. $X$.

Comment: The second equation you have written is a special case of the so-called towering property of conditional expectations.